# Jupyter Notebooks: nbconvert configurations being picked up in jupyter_notebook_config.py file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have a question, the following two lines, from a config file, are configuration options for nbconvert (http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html)

Note that they are note listed under notebook configuration options (http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html)

```
c.TemplateExporter.template_path = ['.', "/Users/williamhenry/Library/Jupyter/templates"]

c.TemplateExporter.template_file = 'printviewlatex'
```

However, the only way I can actually get these configuration options to take effect is to put them in the ***jupyter_notebook_config.py*** file, NOT in the ***jupyter_nbconvert_config.py*** file. This does not make any sense to me. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Are you using nbconvert at the command line, or the 'download as' menu from the notebook? Config files are loaded by the application, so settings in `jupyter_notebook_config.py` will affect converting files using the notebook application.