# Can jupyter notebook web UI be used with custom templates?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have seen many posts on how to use a custom template when rendering LaTeX from a jupyter notebook (eg [hide code in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255288/hide-code-in-jupyter-notebook)) and have successfully implemented the answer described here ([custom template location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51211958/2117681)) eg:

```
~/dev/notebooks$ jupyter nbconvert --to=latex filename.ipynb --Application.log_level='DEBUG'
```

works fine (and applies the custom template specified in my `~/.jupyter/jupyter_nbconvert_config.py`).

But how can I set the jupyter web UI to function the same way using:

> File->Download as->LaTeX (.tex)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you use the File->Download as->LaTeX (.tex)? DO you get any kind of error message?

Comment: there is no error message in the UI.  I'm working to get access to the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [jupyter_notebook_config.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536824/jupyter-notebooks-nbconvert-configurations-being-picked-up-in-jupyter-notebook).  Basically, the jupyter application determines the applied template, which is why it was working fine with:

```
jupyter nbconvert ...
```

but was not working with:

> File->Download as->LaTeX (.tex)

So, by using this ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py:

```
import os

c = get_config()

c.TemplateExporter.template_path = [os.path.expanduser('~/.jupyter/templates'), \
'/usr/local/bin/miniconda3/envs/MyEnv/lib/python3.6/site-\
packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/templates', '.']
c.LatexExporter.template_file = 'custom_latex.tplx'
```

and placing a 'custom_latex.tplx' in the base template directory.  I can set a default template (that does nothing) and then each user can override that default template as they choose (this is for a jupyter hub installation).  If you don't need this generic behavior (ie you aren't on a jupyter hub), you can ignore the default template portion entirely.

For completeness...

default template:

```
((= Nbconvert custom style for LaTeX export =))

((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))

%==============================================================================\
=
% Custom definitions
%==============================================================================\
=
((* block definitions *))
    ((( super() )))

    % Pygments definitions
    ((( resources.latex.pygments_definitions )))

    % Exact colors from NB
    \definecolor{incolor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.5}
    \definecolor{outcolor}{rgb}{0.545, 0.0, 0.0}

    % Don't number sections
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\hspace*{-0.5em}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\hspace*{-0.5em}}

((* endblock definitions *))

% No title
((* block maketitle *))((* endblock maketitle *))



%==============================================================================\
=
% Latex Article
%==============================================================================\
=
% You can customize your LaTeX document here, e.g. you can
% - use a different documentclass like
%   \documentclass{report}
% - add/remove packages (like ngerman)

((* block docclass *))
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
((* endblock docclass *))
```

personal template:

```
((= Nbconvert custom style for LaTeX export =))

((*- extends 'nbextensions.tplx' -*))

%==============================================================================\
=
% Custom definitions
%==============================================================================\
=
((* block definitions *))
    ((( super() )))

    % Pygments definitions
    ((( resources.latex.pygments_definitions )))

    % Exact colors from NB
    \definecolor{incolor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.5}
    \definecolor{outcolor}{rgb}{0.545, 0.0, 0.0}

    % Don't number sections
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\hspace*{-0.5em}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\hspace*{-0.5em}}

((* endblock definitions *))

% No title
((* block maketitle *))((* endblock maketitle *))



%==============================================================================\
=
% Latex Article
%==============================================================================\
=
% You can customize your LaTeX document here, e.g. you can
% - use a different documentclass like
%   \documentclass{report}
% - add/remove packages (like ngerman)

((* block docclass *))
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
% this is all unnecessary when extending nbextensions.tplx + hide_input_all
\usepackage{verbatim} %for {comment}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\renewenvironment{Verbatim}{\comment}{\endcomment}
((* endblock docclass *))
```

Hope this helps someone else - I don't think the documentation is clear on this point at all.